# NPM run * doesn't do anything

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, npm-scripts, npm-run

I was running an Electron project, and everything worked just fine. But now when I run any of the scripts in my package.json (including npm start), it just escapes a line and doesn't do anything.

[image: command line screenshot]

My package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "interclip-desktop",
  "version": "0.0.7",
  "description": "Interclip for desktop",
  "repository": "https://github.com/aperta-principium/Interclip-desktop",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --asar=true --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . Interclip --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Interclip\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . Interclip --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds",
    "win-install": "node installers/windows/createinstaller.js",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "build": "electron-builder --linux",
    "release": "electron-builder --linux --publish always"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Desktop",
    "Interclip"
  ],
  "author": "Filip Troníček",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^7.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.1.0",
    "electron-installer-dmg": "^3.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.1.1",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-winstaller": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.3"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.aperta-principium.interclip",
    "productName": "Interclip",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.utilities"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "icon": false
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "AppImage"
      ],
      "category": "Utility"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried updating NPM, didn't work. When I tried in different projects, also doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 61, accepted):

npm has a `ignore-scripts` configuration key. It's expected value is a Boolean and it's set to `false` by default.

Perhaps it has inadvertently been set to `true`.

To `get`/`set` the `ignore-scripts` configuration you can utilize the [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command:

1. Check its current setting by running:

   ```
   npm config get ignore-scripts
   ```
2. If the aforementioned command returns `true` then reset it to `false` by running:

   ```
   npm config set ignore-scripts false
   ```

Comment: Setting `ignore-scripts` to `false` is [not secure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24tQRwIRP_w&list=PLQhqTW7Ek4ARtck8bgHSWEx90YteK76Ne&t=1046s) actually

Comment: npm config get ignore-scripts and npm --help don't work for me, npm runs and returns nothing instantly.

Comment: Life-saving answer, @RobC. Thank you. I only have a passing familiarity with `npm` and I would never have figured this out on my own. 200 rep bounty coming your way.

Comment: `npm config get ignore-scripts` doesn't return nothing in the terminal, it's empty line again

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an integrated terminal (such as the VsCode integrated terminal) try running your npm "run dev' command from your PowerShell (or cmd) terminal. This error arises as a result of your integrated terminal not recognizing your command (especially if you created your app with a git bash terminal).

Try this, and I hope it helps someone cause it always works for me. Cheers!!!