# npm start doesn't work in a fresh React project

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I have a few react projects and I wanted to create a new one, unforunately "npm start" doesn't execute anything in **any** of my projects anymore. I created a new sample React project with `create-react-app testnpm` and tried to use `npm start`, unfortunately it doesnt to anything, no error message, just nothing in the terminal.

`npm install` works just fine and a package.json exists

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "react-script start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
```

What I tried ? Check wether Node and npm is actually installed

```
➜  portfolio-website git:(folder-structure) ✗ node -v
v12.13.1
➜  portfolio-website git:(folder-structure) ✗ npm -v
6.13.1
```

Restart VSCode and Macbook.
Tryout `npm start` in different projects.

I conclude there must be a deeper issue not with the project itself, but rather with my mac/my settings.

What did I do that might have caused this Issue ?

I recently started implementing typescript in one of my projects, thus I installed proper types in order for Typescript to know React types, I kinda followed along a frontend masters tutorial.

Here is what my Terminal looks like when im trying to run `npm start`

```
➜  portfolio-website git:(folder-structure) ✗ npm start
➜  portfolio-website git:(folder-structure) ✗ npm run build
➜  portfolio-website git:(folder-structure) ✗
```

Any Ideas on where to look or what might help me solve this Issue ?

Comment: looks like your start script is missing an "s" in "react-script(s)"

Comment: have you tried `npm cache clean`?

Comment: Implemented both solutions, neither did work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

The Answer can be found here, props to RobC for helping me find the issue.

[NPM run * doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)