# npm start is doing absolutely nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start

Today I decided to create a react app, a task in which I have done a number of times, and after running the **create-react-app** command in my terminal: I navigated into my new project directory, installed some dependencies I knew I would need, lastly I ran **npm start** and to my surprise -- **nothing happened**. Not only is **npm start** not working, none of the scripts in my package.json file are executing and are completely unresponsive. Furthermore, all executable scripts in all of my React projects have failed to execute since this error has risen.

Last week I was having some trouble installing sqlite3 and had to perform a lot of maintenance in order to get use it in my project; perhaps I deleted a file that is needed in npm that runs scripts? I'll leave a reference to my package.json file below, although I have not altered it much at all.

```
{
  "name": "maps",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance to the whiz who fixes this!

Edit: 
The following is a list of solutions in which I have tried.

- installed the latest `create-react-app` globally
- installed the latest npm and node globally
- deleted node_modules and reinstalled all dependencies using `npm i`
  in my project directory
- checking that my `scripts.test` in my package.json file is set appropriately

Comment: Try `npm run start` instead of `npm start`

Comment: run `npm install` and then `npm start`

Comment: I believe that npm run start and npm start are equivalent statements, no? Regardless, I have tried both as well as `npm run-script start`.

Comment: delete node_modules and package-lock.json both and then do run npm install and npm start

Comment: is it throwing any error?

Comment: *nothing happened*, does `npm -v` work?

Comment: @hussain.codes No error is being thrown. My terminal renders no text nor responses after running `npm start` as well as the corresponding commands.

Comment: All of my other npm commands are working fine -- as far as I know. It is just something with the alised scripts that reside in my package.json file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: YES THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @RobC I completely forgot I set `ignore-scripts` to true; it's funny how it's always something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps:

1. Delete the node_modules folder from your project directory
2. run the command `npm install` in the project directory
3. run `npm start` in the project directory

Comment: I did this earlier, but I still gave it another shot and I'm still having the same problem.