# 'npm start' command doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I'm trying to start a react js project but the `npm start` command doesn't do anything. No error messages. No exceptions. Just nothing.

[image]

I already have a `start` script in the `package.json` file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I've also checked for missing dependencies but nothing is missing.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: maybe it did something but it didnt log it ? is that a posibility ?

Comment: My best guess is that `react-scripts` is hosed somehow. Try the usual `rm -rf node_modules; npm i` (assuming you understand what it means) and retry.

Comment: @AKX tried removing the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled all the dependencies but didn't work.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan no I don't have any missing dependencies

Comment: @Kevin.a the server doesn't start

Comment: @RobC YES! Thank you

Answer (score 24, accepted):

SOLUTION:

My npm `ignore-scripts` was set to `true`. So I set it to `false` and the `npm start` command works.

```
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```

To check if your `ignore-scripts` is `true` or `false`:

```
npm config get ignore-scripts
```

Thanks @RobC for the answer
[NPM run * doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: This is so underrated. I lost 4 hours to find this and fix it.

Comment: Sorry new developer question here, I heard some developers said it is better to turn it off for security purposes...is that good or bad for production or should I turn it off after development only?

Comment: @Metono I did see one of those posts and turn it off for security purposes, and that was what wasted me hours to fix.

Answer (score 3):

try putting `npm run` for scripts, just like

```
npm run start
```

Comment: Still does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a bug. Try to run the command again to see if it works now. Or if the problem persist create another app and follow the instructions. Don't forget to checkout to the project directory as instructed: `cd your_project_name`. And another things: how did you create the app?