# npm start not working in CRA "with no error"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

> node 12.13.1
>
> npm 6.13.1
>
> npm i -g create-react-app
>
> create-reap-app appName
>
> cd appName
>
> npm start

And no error show, just vscode go to next line, and weird part is I have  no error. Deleted almost every thing git node and re-installed those but still not working. It's simply go to next line. What in the world this problem come from?
Thank you.

[image]

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "tested",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: which version of CRA are you using? have you made any changes to the src files?
try YARN too

Comment: create-react-app v3.2.0 , this worked 2days ago ,and why not now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: yes it seems same , i think this answer also work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `npm config list` and see if `ignore-script` is set to true.

Change it to false, both globally and locally.

Comment: `npm config set ignore-scripts false`