# React.js npm start does nothing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Using Mac OS Catalina & Node 12.13.1. I'm trying to launch my React app to no avail.

When I run `$ npm start` in my VS Code terminal, nothing happens. No errors or issues are returned.

I have tried deleting Homebrew, in case there were conflicts. I've uninstalled a Windows SSD partition.
I've tried un/reinstalling node.js. I've tried to edit ~/.zshrc AND ~/.bash_profiles.

I'm simply trying to run my default React app.

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: I've tried using '$ npx create-react-app appName', I've also tried installing create-react-app globally. - Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: When you ran `npx create-react-app appName`, did it successfully create a react app in a `appName` folder and what did you do afterward? Did you change into the `appName` directory before running `npm start`?

Comment: `$ npx create-react-app appName` installed successfully, I changed directory to run `$ npm start`. There are no error messages, the terminal just starts a new line.

Comment: After running `npm start`, can you try waiting for like a minute or two, then visit `http://localhost:3000/` in your browser, see if it loads the create-react-app default page.

Comment: I ran `$ npm start` but again there was no feedback in the Terminal. I waited and loaded `http://localhost:3000/` in Firefox & Chrome. Sadly, nothing. I also tried ports `8000`, `8080` & `5000`. - Again, I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: YES!!!!! @RobC. Amazing! Cheers mates!

Comment: I had the same problem
This page helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything

Answer (score 6):

the same problem encountered for me. expecting a solution.
I am in the root folder i.e.
my project name is amdb, I am inside amdb folder and tried `npm start`, `npm run start`, it returns nothing.

then I found answer on stackoverflow.

---

npm has a `ignore-scripts` configuration key. It's expected value is a Boolean and it's set to `false` by default.

Perhaps it has inadvertently been set to true.

To `get`/`set` the `ignore-scripts` configuration you can utilize the npm-config command:

Check its current setting by running:

```
npm config get ignore-scripts
```

If the aforementioned command returns true then reset it to false by running:

```
npm config set ignore-scripts false
```