# npm start doesn't work for ReactJS anymore

Tags: linux, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

After creating a new ReactJS app using `npx create-react-app testapp`, the command `npm start` (or any other npm-script) doesn't work in ANY of my react projects. It gives no output to console, and the log files in `~/.npm/_logs/` have nothing related to the `start` command.

**Things I have tried:**

- upgrading nodejs and npm
- deleting `package-lock.json` and `node_modules/` and running `npm install` (which works just fine, but doesn't solve the issue with `npm start`)
- restarting the kernel (`5.3.12-arch1-1`)

**Additional info:**

`node -v` = 13.3.0

`npm -v` = 16.13.1

Here is `package.json` from the most recently created app:

```
{
  "name": "react-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution. `npm` had been configured to ignore scripts.

Running `npm config set ignore-scripts false` fixed the problem.