# yarn run start works and npm run start returns nothing

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Why does `$yarn run start` works and `$npm run start` does nothing? 
$ npm -v
6.13.

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I need `$npm run start` to execute. It returns absolutely nothing, not even a warning as if it couldn't parse package.json file.

Comment: You literally have no output in your terminal after running `npm run start` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: @RobC Thanks a lot. That was it.

Comment: Thanks @RobC - I had disabled that setting for security reasons, but of course when you need to run a script, you'll need to enable that option.