# Install different packages depending on node version

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a project that depends on the [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket) package. However, for node 10.x, the latest version (1.0.31) of websocket works, while on node 4.x version 10.0.24 works but the 10.0.31 does *not*. Is it possible to specify *different* package (versions) per nodejs version to handle cases like this, e.g. like so

- node 4.x and older -> websockets 1.0.24
- all other node versions -> websockets 1.0.31

Preferable it should work in both npm and yarn, but if it only works in either that's fine as well.

The node 10 version is used in dev setups, while the node 4.x is used in a legacy embedded platform that cannot run docker or be upgraded.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but also is Node 4 or earlier worth supporting? Node 10 is the oldest that's still getting support and updates: https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider utilizing a [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) script in the `scripts` section of your projects *package.json*. For instance:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "node install-websocket"
},
```

As you can see, the `postinstall` script invokes a nodejs script, arbitrarily named `install-websocket.js`.

**install-websocket.js**

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

const nodeMajorVersion = process.version.replace(/^v/, '').split('.')[0];
const websocketVersion = nodeMajorVersion <= '4' ? '1.0.24' : '1.0.31';

execSync('npm install websocket@' + websocketVersion, {
    cwd: __dirname,
    stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

The `install-websocket.js` script essentially performs the following tasks:

1. Gets the version of node.js using [`process.version`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_version) which returns a string, e.g. `v13.10.1`

   To obtain the *Major* version from that string (i.e. `13` in that aforementioned example) we use a combination of the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) methods.
2. The [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) ascertains 
   which version of `websocket` to subsequently install - based on whether the value of `nodeMajorVersion` is `<= 4`.
3. Finally we *"shell out"* the appropriate `npm install websocket@x.x.x` command using [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).

   <sub>**Note**: If you're concerned about `execSync` being synchronous, then utilize the asynchronous [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) instead.</sub>

---

#### Additional Notes:

- Given the code shown above it assumes the `install-websocket.js` file resides in the root of your project directory, i.e. at the same level as *package.json*.

  ```
  my-project
  ├── package.json
  ├── install-websocket.js
  └── ...
  ```

  It's important for the `install-websocket.js` file to exist at this location for following two reasons:

  1. Primarily, and most importantly, because you'll have noticed that we specify [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) for the value of `execSync`'s [`cwd`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) option. The value of `__dirname` in this context is the pathame to the parent directory of wherever the `install-websocket.js` file resides.

     Essentially by setting the `cwd` option to this specific pathname, (i.e. the path to the project directory), we ensure that when the `npm install websocket@x.x.x` command is run it gets installed in the same location as where your project resides - regardless of whether it's installed locally or globally.
  2. The `postinstall` script in *package.json* expects the `install-websocket.js` file to reside there too. Note how it currently runs; `node install-websocket`, and doesn't assume the file exists elsewhere, i.e. it's not running something like: `node ./some/path/to/install-websocket`
- If consumers of your package have npm [configured to ignore-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything/59018042#59018042) then `websocket`'s simply will not be installed because the `postinstall` script will not be invoked.

Comment: Also because this is essentially a workaround (for want of a better word) for NPM not having a specific built-in feature to install different packages depending on node version, then any reporting tools, such as [this](https://npm.anvaka.com/#/) or [www.npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) itself will not formally show/list `websocket` as a dependency - simply because it's not going to be listed in your project's _package.json_ file.