# Why npm start does not open my React project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, frontend

I would like to learn creating **React** apps. I just recently downloaded node.js and install npm. 
After that I try to run these basic commands in cmd and the last one does nothing (npm v6.14.4, node v12.16.3).
I am new in frontend so i don't really know frameworks, npm and dependency stuff as well.
Why `npm start` doesn't open **localhost:3000** and the project?

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

*(These are from the offical site)*

Just simply nothing happens

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\web\React\my-app>npm start

C:\Users\user\Desktop\web\React\my-app>
```

Comment: what do you see in your console?

Answer (score 0):

Did the first command succeed? It should have create a folder named my-app, containing the new project.
I tried it, and the first command failed, with this error: `npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...+TzBvdSFpX51Nv4MZ\nYY'`
So I tried this command: `npm cache clean --force`, and I tried the first command again.
It worked!

Comment: The first one did I have only problems with the last one.

Comment: Oh Ok. Can you show what is inside your package.json ? Because when you run `npm start`, it runs the script `start` that is defined in your package.json

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxFrH.png

Comment: I know the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything
but thanks for helping!