# Unable to run npm start

Tags: json, npm, webpack

So I am following an online course and I am stuck. I am running the command `npm run start` in cmd and it seems not to be working.

Here is the webpack.config.js file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2DUj.png)

Here is the package.json file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMkHE.png)

Here is the error code I get from cmd:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter>npm run start

> forkify@1.0.0 start C:\Users\user\Desktop\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:65:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\complete-javascript-course-master\\9-forkify\\starter\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-04T10_43_57_046Z-debug.log

C:\Users\user\Desktop\complete-javascript-course-master\9-forkify\starter>
```

What could be possibly wrong please?

Comment: Can you please specify more details? I mean it could be anything, what error you got? Also, you don't need **run** for start script, you can just run `npm start`

Comment: @VaheYavrumian I have added the error code, will really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩no it doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: Please try `npm install --only=dev` and `npm install` and try again