# Node suddenly wont start

Tags: node.js, npm

Ok so yesterday everything works fine. And now i wake up do the same thing run the command "npm start"
and it just wont work anymore.

here is the script

```
"start": "set NODE_ENV=development && node --max-old-space-size=4096 -e 'require(\"./src/index\").start()'"
```

and here is the code

```
module.exports = {
  /**
  * Start the API
  * @return {Promise<boolean>} Return true if the server has been started or else an error
  **/
  start: async () => {
    database.mongoose_connect(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_URI_DATA, process.env.DB_USER_DATA, process.env.DB_PASS_DATA)
    return await server.start(process.env.API_NAME, process.env.HOST, process.env.PORT)
  }
}
```

So yeah my node version is 15.11 im not getting any error or whatsoever it just stop.
Here is some sample. Anyone have a similar issue or have an idea why?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM run \* doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016328/npm-run-doesnt-do-anything)

Comment: i've already try this but it still doesn't work.